# Generalized Ramsey numbers, possibly infinite?

Tags: graph-theory, reference-request, cardinals, ramsey-theory, extremal-graph-theory

The Ramsey number $R(m,n)$ is easy to describe. It's the smallest positive integer such that any graph with at least $R(m,n)$ vertices has at least a clique of size $m$ or an independent set of size $n$. Generalized Ramsey numbers are defined like

> Let $G_1,G_2,\dots,G_m$ be simple graphs. The **generalised Ramsey Number** $r(G_1,G_2,\dots,G_m)$ is the smallest integer $n$ such that every $m$-edge colouring $(E_1,E_2,\dots,E_m)$ of $K_n$ contains, for some $i$, a subgraph isomorphic to $G_i$ in colour $i$.

As far as I'm aware, probabilistc arguments have been used to show the existence of these numbers. But what happens if we take this concept a step further?

Let $\mathcal G = \{G_\gamma\}_{\gamma<\alpha}$ be a family of (possibly infinite multi)graphs induced by a cardinal $\alpha$. Let $r(\mathcal G)$ be the smallest cardinal $\beta$ such that every $\alpha$-edge coloring $\{E_\gamma\}_{\gamma<\alpha}$ of $K_\beta$ contains, for some $\gamma$, a subgraph isomorphic to $G_\gamma$ in color $\gamma$.

Does $r(\mathcal G)$ always exist and has it been studied in such a generalized setting? Searches return work more or less exclusively related to cardinals, removing the graph theory. But maybe this is just a natural generalization I cannot yet grasp?

Comment: I'm no specialist but there are lots of existing results regarding Ramsey theory with infinite cardinals. Quite often, the existence of uncountable cardinals satisfying a Ramsey condition depend on the existence of very large cardinals (such as strongly inaccessible cardinals) and is therefore not provable in ZFC.

Comment: Minor comment: probabilistic arguments have been used to prove lower bounds, but the upper bounds (which you need to show that the number exists) typically don't use the probabilistic method.

Comment: Looking at something like the definition of [Ramsey cardinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramsey_cardinal): (1) I think the departure from graph theory is just because it's not much harder to deal with coloring all finite subsets compared to subsets of size 2 which would be edges of a graph. (2) The not-provable-in-ZFC results are for something stronger, where we color the finite subsets of a set of cardinality $\kappa$, and find a homogeneous set also of cardinality $\kappa$. If the cardinality is allowed to be different, I think that there may be an easy proof, but I'm not a set theorist.

Comment: @ThomasLesgourgues Can you point me to a survey?